# Why my NODE DAYA can't be read in For funtion? and how can I read the data? (C lan)

Tags: c, for-loop, struct

```
int main(void)
{
  srand(time(NULL));  
  init_ATM();
  for (hour = 9;hour < 11;hour++)
  {
    
    for (minutes = 0; minutes < 60; minutes++) 
    {
        
        update_wait();
        enqueue();
        if (minutes % 10 == 0 && (hour == 9 && minutes == 0) != 1)
        {
            is_prime();
        }
        total_time++;
    }
  }
}
```

I have no problem in this situation.

```
    int main(void)
   {
     srand(time(NULL));  
     init_ATM();
     for (hour = 9;hour < 11;hour++)
    {
    
        for (minutes = 0; minutes < 60; minutes++) 
       {
        
           update_wait();
           enqueue();
           if (minutes % 10 == 0 && (hour == 9 && minutes == 0) != 1)
           {
              is_prime();
           }

           printf("%d\n", atm1->front->id); // <<--------------------- what's the problem?
        total_time++;
    }
  }
}
```

but when I insert printf("%d\n", atm1->front->id);, I'm not getting error message but my result is nothing.

```
typedef struct Customer
{
  int id; 
  int service_atm;
  int service_time; 
  int check_VIP;
  int wait_time; 
  struct Customer* link; 
}Customer;


typedef struct ATM
{
  Customer* front;
  Customer* rear;
  int atm_count; 
}ATM;
```

this is my 'Customer' struct & 'ATM' Q type list

and when I using this 'atm1->front->id' type in another funtion like this

```
    int main(void)
{
  srand(time(NULL));  
  init_ATM();
  for (hour = 9;hour < 11;hour++)
  {
    
    for (minutes = 0; minutes < 60; minutes++) 
    {
        
        update_wait();
        enqueue();
        if (minutes % 10 == 0 && (hour == 9 && minutes == 0) != 1)
        {
            is_prime();
        }
        total_time++;
    }
  }
  printf("%d\n", atm1->front->id);  // <------------------------------------- 
}
```

it's ok in this situation. but it isn't the result that I want. this include just two results. i want to get the result like this
'''
3
6
7
13
19
...
<= 9 past 59
2
5
7
13
25
...
<= 10 past 59
'''

Comment: Where is `init_ATM` defined?

Comment: I defined that. It's just partial in my code.  I'm wondering C grammer. why Q type can't be called from 'for' function. Would it be better to add all the parts? I'm worried because it's too long.

Comment: for is a reserved c keyword. You can't use it for any variable name.